# Tic Tac Toe in Java, trying to figure out how to reset the program

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out how to write the code to reset my program/ clear the board so tic tac toe can be played again. It is supposed to have a prompt that asks "do you want to play again" after a win/tie. It's the final part I am trying to figure out.

Board:

```
public class Board {

    private char[][] board;


    public Board() {

        char[][] temp = {{'1', '2', '3'}, {'4', '5', '6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};
        board = temp;

    }

    public void printBoard() {

        for (char[] row : board) {
            for (char cell : row) {
                System.out.printf("| %c ", cell);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public boolean isCellAvailable(int number) {

        if (1 <= number && number <= 9) {
            int row = (number - 1) / 3;
            int col = (number - 1) % 3;
            if (board[row][col] == 'X' || board[row][col] == 'O') return false;
            else return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    public void place(int number, char marker) {
        int row = (number - 1) / 3;
        int col = (number - 1) % 3;
        board[row][col] = marker;
    }

    public boolean isWinner() {

        if (board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][1] == board[0][2]) return true;
        else if (board[1][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[1][2]) return true;
        else if (board[2][0] == board[2][1] && board[2][1] == board[2][2]) return true;

        else if (board[0][0] == board[1][0] && board[1][0] == board[2][0]) return true;
        else if (board[0][1] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][1]) return true;
        else if (board[0][2] == board[1][2] && board[1][2] == board[2][2]) return true;

        else if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2]) return true;
        else if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0]) return true;

        return false;

    }
}
```

Driver:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Board board = new Board();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        board.printBoard();
        int moves = 0;
        while (true) {

            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Player 1: Enter your move: ");
                int cell = scanner.nextInt();
                if (board.isCellAvailable(cell)) {
                    board.place(cell, 'X');
                    board.printBoard();
                    moves += 1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Cell not available.");
                }
            }
            if (board.isWinner()) {
                System.out.println("Player 1 wins.");
                break;
            }
            if (moves == 9) {
                System.out.println("Draw. Game ended.");
                break;
            }

            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Player 2: Enter your move: ");
                int cell = scanner.nextInt();
                if (board.isCellAvailable(cell)) {
                    board.place(cell, 'O');
                    board.printBoard();
                    moves += 1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Cell not available.");
                }
            }
            if (board.isWinner()) {
                System.out.println("Player 2 wins.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider that most of the logic in your `main` method handles the task of playing one game from start to end.  Now you need another loop around all that which, after a game has been played, asks the user if he/she wants another game and keeps going as long as the user answers "yes".  As for resetting the board, I'd suggest simply creating a new `Board` object at the start of each game.

Answer (score 1):

You need another loop in order to manage the *Play again* option. If the player wants to play again, a `new Board()` is created and the `moves` are reseted as well. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        Board board = new Board();
        board.printBoard();
        int moves = 0;

        while(true){

            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Player 1: Enter your move: ");
                int cell = scanner.nextInt();
                if (board.isCellAvailable(cell)) {
                    board.place(cell, 'X');
                    board.printBoard();
                    moves += 1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Cell not available.");
                }
            }
            if (board.isWinner()) {
                System.out.println("Player 1 wins.");
                break;
            }
            if (moves == 9) {
                System.out.println("Draw. Game ended.");
                break;
            }

            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Player 2: Enter your move: ");
                int cell = scanner.nextInt();
                if (board.isCellAvailable(cell)) {
                    board.place(cell, 'O');
                    board.printBoard();
                    moves += 1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Cell not available.");
                }
            }
            if (board.isWinner()) {
                System.out.println("Player 2 wins.");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to play again? Press 1, otherwise press 0")
        int option = scanner.nextInt();
        if(option == 0) break;
    }
}
```